# How to remove the first word of a string

Tags: string, loops, char

What I have done will probably be confusing but I tried doing it by replacing every letter to nothing until it finds a space.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mening.length(); i++) {
    if ((int)mening.charAt(i) != 32 && stop == false) {
        mening = mening.replace(String.valueOf(mening.charAt(i)), "");
    } else {
        stop = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer would depend on what language this is written in.  Also, what *specific* problem(s) are you having with this?

Answer (score 0):

Just split string by space, remove the first item and join the rest together.

```
mening = mening.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
```